# Images not showing until I resize the window?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working on a site built on wordpress and trying to update the company team page. The section is a horizontal container with images of each member.

However, I run into an issue where some images don't appear on a desktop viewport, i.e. the first and last images show but not the ones in the middle. The rest of the images only populate when I resize the screen width to a mobile screen size.

My php template:

```
<div id="team-container" class="uk-column-1-1@s uk-column-1-3@m uk-column-1-5@l">
  <?php if ( have_rows( 'team_members' ) ) : ?>
  <?php while ( have_rows( 'team_members' ) ) : the_row(); ?>
  <a href="<?php the_sub_field('linkedin_url'); ?>">
    <div class="team-members">
      <?php if ( get_sub_field( 'image' ) ) { ?>
      <img class="team-members-img" alt data-src="<?php the_sub_field( 'image' ); ?>" data-srcset="<?php the_sub_field( 'image' ); ?>" uk-img>
      <?php } ?>
      <div class="team-members-name-layer">
        <h4 class="team-members-name"><strong><?php the_sub_field('name'); ?></strong><br><span class="team-members-positions"><?php the_sub_field('positions'); ?></span></h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
  <?php else : ?>
  <?php // no rows found ?>
  <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you check the DOM to confirm if `<img>` tags were rendereds?

Comment: Yes, the img tags are rendered. However, the browser shows a blank box.

Comment: If you replace `data-src` by `src` it works?

Comment: Are you sure that all thumbnail versions (data-srcset) have been generated by WordPress?